# Are writs rooted in equity?

Tags: england-and-wales, common-law, legal-history, equity, writ-of-mandamus

Another answer I came across recently mentioned that orders for specific performance ie mandatory injunctions formerly called mandamus were writs. Conversely so were other writs such as certiorari. What, historically, was a “writ”? Are they a legacy of equity, rather than law, back when they were separate disciplines?

Answer (score 3):

### No

A [writ](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/w/writ.asp) is simply an order issued under legal authority for someone to do or not do something.

Today the word is usually associated with orders by a court but historically, they applied to administrative and parliamentary orders as well. Technically, a “No parking” sign is a writ.

Comment: Yes, the good old writ of non stationandi.

Comment: No wait, no parking is an imperative, so it would be stationate in plural present active form.

Comment: In the modern sense, writs are pretty much exclusively court orders directed at government officials, so a no parking sign would not be a writ.

Comment: @IKnowNothing Romanes eunt domus

Answer (score 2):

Writs are not unique to equity. Writs developed as essentially template actions and associated orders in both law courts and chancery. They eventually crystalized around a fixed set of wrongs and remedies which developed into modern day categories of action and relief. See generally: Frederic William Maitland & Sir Frederick Pollock, *The History of English Law before the Time of Edward I, vol. 1*, "[CHAPTER VII: The Age of Bracton](https://oll.libertyfund.org/title/maitland-the-history-of-english-law-before-the-time-of-edward-i-vol-1#lf1541-01_label_633)."